# Conditional use of initWithStyle UITableView

Tags: ios6, uitableview, segue

I have one UITableView class that can load a variety of data.  All the actions on the data that is loaded will be the same regardless of what the data is, so I figured it would be best to keep it all in the same class. The problem I'm running into is that for one set of data, I need the UITableView to use the style UITableViewStyleGrouped, and the rest to use UITableViewStylePlain.

I was able to get this to work in prepareForSegue by using the following if statement:

```
if([whatToLoad isEqualToString:@"Sets"]){
            [[segue destinationViewController] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        }
        else
            [[segue destinationViewController] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

But then Xcode gives me a warning on both of them of "Expression result unused". Is there something else I can do to achieve the same result without the warning? Or do I have to create a different class for the one set of data that needs a grouped table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple table view controllers in the storyboard file, and set the "Class" to the same `UITableViewController` subclass for each of them. So you can use the same controller code for each of them, but one has a "grouped" table view and the others have a "plain" table view.

Calling

```
[[segue destinationViewController] initWithStyle:...]
```

seems risky to me, because the destination view controller is an already allocated and initialized instance, and `initXXX` functions are generally allowed to return a *different* instance.

Comment: If i create a second view controller, and set it's Class to the same subclass, how do I tell it which view controller to use?

Comment: @Nick: Can't you use different segues, as you did before? (I hope that I understood you question correctly and that this helps.)

Comment: Wow. I feel silly right now for not thinking of this. That is exactly what I needed to do. I was under the impression that if I used the same class for multiple view controllers I would have to use the same segue to get to them as well. Thank you, this works perfectly.